# Simple wildcard use

Tags: variables, batch-file, wildcard, dir

EDIT: I have just changed the if to an if else

`IF "%CD:~1%"==":\" (
    set FIR=%CD:~0,2%
) ELSE (
    set FIR=%CD%
)`

Trying to use a wildcard to detect if a batch file is on the root directory (As root causes there to be a backslash at the end of the DIR)

I need to determine with a simple if statement whether it is *:\ or not. I have tried using wildcards *:\ and ?:\ but to no avail. If I use the drive letter, example: G:\ it works.

```
if %CD%==G:\ echo SOMETHING WRONG HERE
```

works perfectly well, until the drive letter changes. Where as

```
if %CD%==?:\ echo SOMETHING WRONG HERE
```

or

```
if "%CD%"=="?:\" echo SOMETHING WRONG HERE
```

Doesn't work.

EDIT: After reading up it turns out if and wildcards are not compatible!

Comment: Wildcards

Wildcards are not supported by IF, so %COMPUTERNAME%==SS6* will not match SS64

A workaround is to retrieve the substring and compare just those characters:
SET _prefix=%COMPUTERNAME:~0,3%
IF %_prefix%==SS6 GOTO they_matched

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
if "%CD:~-2%"==":\" (echo root) else echo NOT root
```

see docu `help set`.

Comment: this might be more accurate `if "%cd:~-2%"==":\" echo is root`

Comment: @foxidrive for what case are you thinking?

Comment: If the path used is c:\abc\ then your code will also return that it is the root.  With my suggestion it will return that it is not the root.  It's perhaps a moot point as %cd% will return d:\abc and your code will work fine in all cases.

Comment: @foxidrive yes, if you actively assign a value to `cd`. But nevertheless, it might be safer.

Comment: @Foxdrive Actually my script later on writes the directories /abc/Icon itself. So when run from root it writes C:\\abc\Icon else %CD% does work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are not usable within IF statements in command.